# How to find whether user is using browser in mobile or system in Scala and play framework?

Tags: scala

I searching for an answer where through a request, how am i supposed to find whether user in viewing web page in system browser or in mobile browser application. For example, lets take forgot password i am sending an link to user email, where user should click the link to set new password, if he uses mobile browser application i should send to mobile screen or other-case i have to send to web browser in system. Can anyone you guys tell me, how to achieve this in Scala and Play framework(User-agent request).

Comment: Just make it a proper webpage and everything will be fine. You don't have to send anybody anywhere

Comment: I am not sure whether its going to work,anyway thanks man lets see

Answer (score 0):

Following should get you user-agent,

```
val isMobile = request.headers.get("User-Agent") match {
  case Some(v) => v.indexOf("Mobile") != -1
  case None    => false
}
```

As Jens Shauder mentioned in his comment, this is not necessary for the use case you have mentioned.